# Smooth the y-axis and then extrapolate using R

Tags: r, data.table

In the `data.table` below, I want to smooth the values on y-axis, which are not aligned to the x-y curve, and then extrapolate to find the missing values.
E.g. in group `P1`, value y = 0.850 at x = 77.5 does not align with the rest of the curve and this y value should be less than the previous value y.

The desired result is that -

1. First, all the non-NA values should be smoothed to fit the curve. In the image below, the values in red circles are not aligned with rest of the curve.
2. After smoothing, fill up the NA values using extrapolation

```
test_dt = structure(list(group = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", 
"P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P2", 
"P2"), x = c(74, 75, 76, 77, 77.5, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 70, 81, 
82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 98, 
105), y = c(1.05, 0.575, 0.275, 0.125, 0.85, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 14.2, 3.7, 2.875, 2.175, 1.575, 1.1, 0.7, 0.475, 0.3, 0.65, 
0.125, 0.925, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-29L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55a2192149d0>, index = integer(0))

    group     x      y
 1:    P1  74.0  1.050
 2:    P1  75.0  0.575
 3:    P1  76.0  0.275
 4:    P1  77.0  0.125
 5:    P1  77.5  0.850
 6:    P1  78.0     NA
 7:    P1  79.0     NA
 8:    P1  80.0     NA
 9:    P1  81.0     NA
10:    P1  82.0     NA
11:    P2  70.0 14.200
12:    P2  81.0  3.700
13:    P2  82.0  2.875
14:    P2  83.0  2.175
15:    P2  84.0  1.575
16:    P2  85.0  1.100
17:    P2  86.0  0.700
18:    P2  87.0  0.475
19:    P2  88.0  0.300
20:    P2  89.0  0.650
21:    P2  90.0  0.125
22:    P2  91.0  0.925
23:    P2  92.0     NA
24:    P2  93.0     NA
25:    P2  94.0     NA
26:    P2  95.0     NA
27:    P2  96.0     NA
28:    P2  98.0     NA
29:    P2 105.0     NA
    group     x      y

p_load(ggplot2)
ggplot(test_dt, aes(x, y, group = group)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

Here is what I have tried for step 1, but could not align the points -

```
test_dt = na.omit(test_dt)
test_dt[, y_1 := round(lowess(x = x, y = y, f = 0.1)$y, 3), by = c("group")]
> test_dt
    group    x      y    y_1
 1:    P1 74.0  1.050  1.050
 2:    P1 75.0  0.575  0.575
 3:    P1 76.0  0.275  0.275
 4:    P1 77.0  0.125  0.125
 5:    P1 77.5  0.850  0.850
 6:    P2 70.0 14.200 14.200
 7:    P2 81.0  3.700  3.700
 8:    P2 82.0  2.875  2.875
 9:    P2 83.0  2.175  2.175
10:    P2 84.0  1.575  1.575
11:    P2 85.0  1.100  1.100
12:    P2 86.0  0.700  0.700
13:    P2 87.0  0.475  0.475
14:    P2 88.0  0.300  0.300
15:    P2 89.0  0.650  0.650
16:    P2 90.0  0.125  0.125
17:    P2 91.0  0.925  0.925
```

Comment: Unless you are using magic, there is no way to *align* the points. You probably just have to remove the points and consider them as *extreme values* ie *outliers*, and predict them using the fitted curve. Otherwise, using all the data will somehow influence the curve

Comment: Is there a way to detect which of these points are not aligned to the curve?

Comment: Not really. Because if you fit the curve using all the points, the curve will be shifted away from the points. Unless you decide on a cutout/threshold that if the points are at least a certain distance from the curve then they should be left out and the cureve be refitted again. But in this case, you will be doing curve fitting which is even more difficult by itself

Comment: Also consider drawing `P1` by itself. Note that there are only 5 points. How would you decide that the last point is the one that is not aligned to the curve? What if the middle two are somehow way below the curve making it seem that the fifth point is way above the curve? There is really no way to tell which points are in the curve, unless you have an equation/function that estimates the curve

Comment: Lastly I would advice you to ask this question on [corss validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) where by there are experts on curve fitting